# Resharper 8 could not find implementations of interfaces

Tags: c#, resharper, resharper-8.0

In some cases (Interface and implementation in different projects of the same solution) Ctrl + F12 (go to implementation) does not work. It says "Implementations of IYourService were not found". The same thing could happen when you want to implement some member. Clean + rebuild could help but not always.

It seems that Resharper 7 does not have such problem.

Have somebody met that issue? How to fix it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you reproduce it and describe the steps required?

Comment: Also, have you tried clearing the ReSharper cache, and possibly checking if there's an update to ReSharper?

Comment: Clear cache don't help. Update from 8.0.1 to 8.0.2 fixes problem for some time. I couldn't provide more info to reproduce - it seems random, but occurs when you try to go/implement to different assembly.

Comment: I've been having this same issue since updating to 8.02. Are you still experiencing this?

Comment: Yes, even with 8.1 beta

Comment: I can also confirm this bug (R# build 8.1.23.546).

Comment: I am also having a similar issue with R# 8.1.23.546. Is anyone aware if a bug report has been filed? This is not only impacting navigation, but it also causes refactoring to not work properly. For instance, renaming an interface method will not rename the implementations.

Comment: Another 'same here' on this one. It does appear to be where the implementation is in a different assembly.

Comment: Sounds like a bug of ReSharper or at least only JetBrains guys can answer it.

Comment: I also have the same problem with now 8.2 in VS2013. MVC 5

Comment: @BahaiResearch.com Have you tried my suggestion below : from VS2013 menu bar, `Resharper` --> `Options` --> `Clear Caches`, then reopen your solution ? It works for me with R# 8.1 and MVC.

Comment: Dio - Yes, it does not work. I have the latest Resharper. Seems to fail when you are in project A, interfaces in project B and implementation in project C

Comment: The bug is there with R# Build 8.2.0.2160 on 2014-03-21T00:53:08 on VS Ultimate 2013 Update 2 & 3.

Comment: I have the same bug in R# 8.2.2 (8.2.2000.5102). Microsoft Visual Studio Premium 2013 Version 12.0.30723.00 Update 3.

Answer (score 14):

I tried clear the Resharper Cache: `Resharper` --> `Options` --> `Environment` --> `General` --> `Clear Caches`.

Then I close and reopen the solution to let the cache rebuild.

It works with Resharper 8.1 build.

Comment: This did not work for me with Resharper 8.2.
Deleting %localAppData%\Local\JetBrains\ReSharper\v8.2\SolutionCaches did not work either.

Comment: Have you tried close and reopen the solution ? And what is your Resharper cache location ? You should use the `Clear Caches` button of Resharper to ensure clearing the right cache.

Comment: Yes, i have tried all of that. I have tried deleting the cache folder manually, and also by pressing the Clear Caches button.

Comment: We're experiencing the same problem on my team.  Alt+End doesn't always go to implementations and we have to go find them manually.  Oddly, it works for some interfaces and not others.

Answer (score 2):

I've faced same problem with a quite difference for only one solution which is in the TFS online. Resharper could not find implementations in the only one project in my solution. And this same situation was occuring on other team users machine for same solution.

So I've tried to this way and it worked for me:

- Clean the solution
- Go to `Resharper > Options > Environment > General > Store Caches in`
- Change cache folder from `User local settings folder` to `Solution folder`
- Click `Save` button
- Rebuilt solution

Answer (score 0):

We had the same problem and it turned out that something in our MVC project that referenced the library was causing it.  After recreating the MVC project with MVC 5, the problem disappeared.